# Interrupting & Non-interrumpting events can be for throwing and catching?

Tags: bpmn

I have a question about the BPMN notation. Does anybody know if interrupting/non-interrumpting events can be for throwing and catching. The specification (v2.0) doesn't define this explicitly (or maybe I missed it) but it seems it only defines the icon for catching the event.

Maybe I am misunderstanding the use that events attached to the border of an activity have.

If I had to take a guess I would say that it is only catching since events attached to the border of an activity are catching things that happen inside subprocesses or activities. Things that happen outside the scope of the activity or subprocess do not influence what can happen inside it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

interrupting (int) /non-interrumpting (n-int) are only catching events. they can be used in sub-processes and as boundary events.

the diffrence between int and n-int as a boundary event is:
- [int] when fired the action is blocked
- [n-int] the event is fired but the action still goes on.

[here](http://www.bpmb.de/images/BPMN2_0_Poster_EN.pdf) you can see a simple doc with all the grammar. if you look on the right side you can see that no trowing can be (n-int).
if you think about that, trowing event does not have to wait for do their action, so n-int or int does not make any sense.